# WPF combobox add item

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

In Access 2010 (and others?) if you assign a 'List Items Edit Form' to a combo box, you get a semi transparent edit icon appear when you open the combo box, which you can click on and open a form to add/edit items in the combo box's data source. Does anyone know if this can be replicated in WPF/Xaml and if so how? It looks very slick and far better than a button next to the combo box which is how I do it at the moment ( I have found lots of examples of how to add an item at the top of the combo box list but that isn't what I'm after

Many Thanks
Kev T

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a complete answer, but I have some ideas. I've tried to think it all through, but there are probably things that aren't quite right or could be done better.

Create a new class that inherits from ComboBox; let's call it EditableComboBox. Give it a TemplatePart of type Button whose name is PART_EditButton. Also add a dependency property to EditableComboBox of type object; let's call it EditorContent. (This will be the content of the popup dialog.)

Override OnApplyTemplate to get a reference to the button (using GetTemplateChild) and attach an event handler to the button's Click event. When the Click event fires, create and show a child Window, and set its Content property to EditorContent. Set its DataContext property to the DataContext of the EditableComboBox.

Use Blend to create a copy of the default ControlTemplate for Button; let's call it MyButtonControlTemplate. Change the button's Opacity to something less than 1, and add a Storyboard to the MouseOver VisualState that sets Opacity to 1.

Use Blend to create a copy of the default ControlTemplate for ComboBox; let's call it EditableComboBoxTemplate. See the Popup node? Add another transparent row to its child Grid, and add a button in that row named PART_EditButton. Set the button's Template to MyButtonControlTemplate. Then create a default style for EditableComboBox that sets the Template to EditableComboBoxTemplate.

When using EditableComboBox, set its EditorContent property to something that can edit the items, perhaps a Grid containing a ListBox bound to the same ItemsSource as the EditableComboBox.

I hope that's at least somewhat helpful. I'd like to provide sample code, but unfortunately I don't have enough time at the moment. This is an interesting question, so I'll try to check back later to see if someone else has given you a better idea and/or answer further questions you might have.

Comment: Andrew, thanks you for your reply, you have obviously given this a lot of thought and I am grateful. I shall work through your idea next week and report back (can't do anything this weekend).
Many thanks